# Arranging AudioBuffers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audiobuffer

I would like to write a program that "arranges" multiple audio buffers. Similar to a DAW, I want to "layer" audio tracks on top of each other at custom timestamps. Is this even possible, and if so, how would I implement it?

> I apologize in advance for this extremely general question, but I couldn't find any good resources on this topic. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

First, load your audio data into [`AudioBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) instances.

Next, you want to create an [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext), which is basically the root of a graph of connected nodes where your audio flows about.

Now, create an [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) for each AudioBuffer and connect it to the audio context's destinationNode.  This basically plugs a buffer player directly to the output.

From there, you can call [`.start()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start) on your AudioBufferSourceNode instances to play them back immediately, or schedule them to play at some point in the future.

Comment: Is it possible to generate the result without "playing" the audio? I would like to export the AudioBuffer instead.

Comment: @KentoNishi Yes, an OfflineAudioContext is used for this, and can process your audio faster than realtime.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext

Comment: How would offsetting specific audio tracks work in this implementation? I would like to choose when each track starts in the resulting audio.

Comment: @KentoNishi Read the documentation for `.start()` that I linked to...

Comment: Sorry! I didn't really read :P